# Using Roku's USB for ECP 'query' commands?

Tags: usb, arduino-esp8266, roku, brightscript

I added an ESP8266 nodeMCU for TV and SoundBar IR commands. It also provides a LAN server delivering an HTML/javascript based remote controller to my devices - computer, tablets and mobile phones.

I use this same remote setup for both a Roku4 w/ an old Dynex (dumb) TV as well as a newer TCL Roku Smart TV w/ soundbar.

Question is, can I access Roku data as used to be provided by ECP queries like '/query/apps' and '/query/active-app' via the Roku's USB port? ...if not, what is required to accomplish this end?

Answer (score 1):

The definitive answer from the Roku folks is no. It's use is for data storage devices.